# when divide is selected and a zero is entered for division display message

Tags: vb.net

VB.Net,Calculator project that has 2 Text Boxes for number entry, a drop down list, "OperatorList", for math operator, and a Calculate button.

I need to display a message on the "Result Label", not a message box, stating "You cannot divide by zero". My VB.Net code is below but the message won't display. Please help.

```vb
Protected Sub CalculateButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles CalculateButton.Click
    If ValueBox1.Text.Length > 0 AndAlso ValueBox2.Text.Length > 0 Then

        Dim result As Double = 0
        Dim value1 As Double = Convert.ToDouble(ValueBox1.Text)
        Dim value2 As Double = Convert.ToDouble(ValueBox2.Text)

        Select Case OperatorList.SelectedValue
            Case "+"
                result = value1 + value2
            Case "-"
                result = value1 - value2
            Case "*"
                result = value1 * value2
            Case "/"
                result = value1 / value2
        End Select
        If OperatorList.SelectedValue = "/" Then
            If value2 <> 0 Then
                ResultLable.Text = "You cannot divide by Zero"
            Else
                result = value1 / value2
            End If
        End If
        ResultLable.Text = result.ToString()
    Else
        ResultLable.Text = String.Empty
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please only choose one language tag. In this case, it appears to be vb.net.

Comment: You would probably get a lot more help if you posted the C# version of your code and removed any mention of VB.NET. There's more C# activity on Stack Overflow than VB.NET.

Comment: So what is happening instead? I would bet the app is throwing an error. You do the actual division by zero before you ever check whether a zero has been entered -- you are doing the division in the CASE statements.

Comment: Can you explain what you believe `If value2 <> 0 Then` means?

Comment: Hello, I adjusted it to only be one language, VB.Net.

Comment: The debugger is your friend.

Comment: Eric, I believe I'm checking for the 0 in the second text box. If so then it displays message, well supposed to.

Comment: A little bit late in checking if value2 is zero, no?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're over-writing the resultlable.text property with the value of the result variable after the divide by 0 check if statements.

Doing something such as exiting the sub after writing out the divide by zero message should give you the result you're hoping for.

Then secondly, you were checking if value2 was not 0 as the divide by zero check, when it needs to check to see if the value is zero.

```
 If OperatorList.SelectedValue = "/" Then
     If value2 = 0 Then
         ResultLable.Text = "You cannot divide by Zero"
         Exit Sub
     Else
         result = value1 / value2
    End If
End If
```

Comment: Thank You Stephen for the explanation, It helped make the difference in understanding what I was doing wrong without knowing it.